# core-plot x-axis label not visible - bounding rects?

Tags: macos, core-plot

Using the vertical bar chart sample as a start, I created a chart whose y values are 0..1, x values 1..n but the x label index supplied for CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation cell of my data source doesn't appear; I don't use y-axis labels.

I suspect I'm clipping them.  Is there a way, like in the old IB, to draw the various graph region's bounding rect?

The x-axis plot labels are a non-numeric string as in the example.  What did I break?  Here's my setup

```
//
//  InfoBarView.m

#import "InfoBarView.h"

//  Item index to color mapping for legend symbols not item related
static NSUInteger fldMapping[] = { 5, 6, 7, 0 };

static const BOOL kUseHorizontalBars = NO;

static NSArray <__kindof NSString *> const* kTargets = nil;
static NSArray <__kindof NSString *> const* kGetters = nil;

@interface BarChart()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong, nullable) CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation * symbolTextAnnotation;
@end

@implementation BarChart
@synthesize symbolTextAnnotation;
@synthesize plotData;

+ (void)initialize
{
    kTargets = [@[ @"grpA" , @"grpB", @"grpC", @"grpD" ] retain];
    kGetters = [@[ @"fldA", @"fldB", @"fldC", @"fldD" ] retain];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //  Get our orig scaling
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)killGraph
{
    if ( self.graphs.count )
    {
        CPTGraph * graph = self.defaultGraph;

        CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *annotation = self.symbolTextAnnotation;
        if ( annotation )
        {
            [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:annotation];
            self.symbolTextAnnotation = nil;
        }
    }

    [super killGraph];
}

- (void)generateData
{
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    NSUInteger rndx = controller.barDataRanking;
    NSArray * rankings = @[ @"Rank", @"Runs" ];
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;
    CPTGraph * graph = [self defaultGraph];

    CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation * annotation = self.symbolTextAnnotation;
    if ( annotation )
    {
        if (graph)
        {
            [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:annotation];
            self.symbolTextAnnotation = nil;
        }
    }

    //  Update X title with new controller index
    if (graph)
    {
        graph.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Past Performances by %@", rankings[rndx]];
    }

    //  Figure out our rank selector
    NSString * rankSelectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@Compare:",
                                   kTargets[controller.barDataIndex],
                                   rankings[rndx]];
    SEL dataRanking = NSSelectorFromString(rankSelectorName);

    self.plotData = (id)[group.items sortedArrayUsingSelector:dataRanking];
}

- (void)renderInGraphHostingView:(nonnull CPTGraphHostingView *)hostingView
                       withTheme:(nullable CPTTheme *)theme
                        animated:(BOOL)animated
{
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR || TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    CGRect bounds = hostingView.bounds;
#else
    CGRect bounds = NSRectToCGRect(hostingView.bounds);
#endif
    InfoController * controller = ((InfoBarView *)hostingView.superview).controller;
    CPTGraph * graph = [[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds] autorelease];
    NSString * titles = @"fldA  fldB  fldC  fldD";
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;
    CPTBarPlot * barPlot;

    //  Initially we default by rank
    self.title = @"Past Performances by Rank";

    [self addGraph:graph toHostingView:hostingView];

    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    if ( kUseHorizontalBars )
    {
        graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom += self.titleSize;
    }
    else
    {
        graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft += self.titleSize;
    }

    //  Add plot space for bar charts
    CPTXYPlotSpace * barPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    [barPlotSpace setScaleType:CPTScaleTypeCategory forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateX];
    if ( kUseHorizontalBars )
    {
        barPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-10.0) length:@120.0];
        barPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-1.0) length:@11.0];
    }
    else
    {
        barPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.5) length:@(group.itemCount)];
        barPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.05) length:@1.0];
    }
    barPlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    [graph addPlotSpace:barPlotSpace];
    barPlotSpace.delegate = self;

    // Create grid line styles
    CPTMutableLineStyle * majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];

    CPTMutableLineStyle * minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25];

    // Create axes
    CPTXYAxisSet * axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis * x = axisSet.xAxis;
    {
        x.majorIntervalLength           = (kUseHorizontalBars ? @10.0 : @1.0);
        x.minorTicksPerInterval         = (kUseHorizontalBars ? 9 : 0);
        x.orthogonalPosition            = (kUseHorizontalBars ? @(-0.5) : @0.0);

        x.majorGridLineStyle            = majorGridLineStyle;
        x.minorGridLineStyle            = minorGridLineStyle;
        x.axisLineStyle                 = nil;
        x.majorTickLineStyle            = nil;
        x.minorTickLineStyle            = nil;

        x.labelOffset = self.titleSize * CPTFloat(2.5);
        if ( kUseHorizontalBars )
        {
            x.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@10.0];
            x.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.5) length:@(group.itemCount)];
        }
        else
        {
            x.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.5) length:@(group.itemCount)];
            x.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@(1.0)];
        }
        x.plotSpace                     = barPlotSpace;
    }

    CPTXYAxis * y = axisSet.yAxis;
    {
        y.majorIntervalLength           = (kUseHorizontalBars ? @1.0 : @10.0);
        y.minorTicksPerInterval         = (kUseHorizontalBars ? 0 : 9);
        y.orthogonalPosition            = (kUseHorizontalBars ? @0.0 : @(-0.5) );

        y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks   = 8;
        y.majorGridLineStyle            = majorGridLineStyle;
        y.minorGridLineStyle            = minorGridLineStyle;
        y.axisLineStyle                 = nil;
        y.majorTickLineStyle            = nil;
        y.minorTickLineStyle            = nil;
        y.labelOffset                   = self.titleSize * CPTFloat(0.175);
        y.titleLocation                 = (kUseHorizontalBars ? @55.0 : @(group.itemCount-1));

        if ( kUseHorizontalBars )
        {
            y.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.5) length:@10.0];
            y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@100.0];
        }
        else
        {
            y.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.5) length:@(group.itemCount)];
            y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.5) length:@(group.itemCount)];
        }
        y.title                         = titles;
        y.titleOffset                   = self.titleSize * CPTFloat(0.25);
        [barPlotSpace addCategory:title[seg] forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateY];
        y.plotSpace                     = barPlotSpace;
    }

    //  Set axes
    graph.axisSet.axes = @[x, y];

    //  Create a shared bar line style
    CPTMutableLineStyle * barLineStyle  = [[[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
    barLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    barLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];

    //  Marshall Y axis into individual plot identifiers
    NSArray * title = [titles componentsSeparatedByString:@"  "];

    CPTMutableTextStyle * blackTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    blackTextStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];

    //  Create bar plot(s)
    for (int seg=0; seg<title.count; seg++)
    {
        barPlot = [[[CPTBarPlot alloc] init] autorelease];

        barPlot.lineStyle           = barLineStyle;
        barPlot.fill                = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorAtIndex:seg]];
        barPlot.barBasesVary        = YES;
        barPlot.barCornerRadius     = 4.0;
        barPlot.barWidth            = @0.5;
        barPlot.barsAreHorizontal   = kUseHorizontalBars;
        barPlot.dataSource          = self;
        barPlot.delegate            = self;
        barPlot.identifier          = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d",title[seg],seg],
        barPlot.labelTextStyle      = blackTextStyle;
        barPlot.labelOffset         = 0.0;
        [graph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:barPlotSpace];
        NSLog(@"render:%@", barPlot.identifier);
    }

    //  Add X category per slot
    for (Item * item in plotData)
    {
        [barPlotSpace addCategory:item.numb forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateX];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Delegate

- (void)Plot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot dataLabelWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
//  NSString * barID = (NSString *)[[(id)plot.identifier componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Data label for '%@' was selected at record %d.", plot.identifier, (int)index);
}

- (CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
{
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;

    int sndx = index % group.itemCount;
    Item * item = (Item *)[self.plotData objectAtIndex:sndx];

    CPTMutableTextStyle * textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    textStyle.color = [CPTColor colorAtIndex:item.foreRGB];
    textStyle.textAlignment = CPTTextAlignmentCenter;
    textStyle.fontSize = 24;
    plot.labelOffset = 0;

    CPTMutableShadow * shadow = [CPTMutableShadow shadow];
    shadow.shadowColor = [CPTColor blackColor];//colorAtIndex:item.backRGB];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,-1);
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2.0f;
    plot.labelShadow = shadow;

    CPTTextLayer * textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:item.numb.squish style:textStyle];

    return [textLayer autorelease];
}

- (void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CGFloat floor = [[self valueForPlot:plot field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase recordIndex:index] doubleValue];
    CGFloat value = [[self valueForPlot:plot field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip recordIndex:index] doubleValue];
    CGFloat runs = 0;

    NSString * barID = (NSString *)[[(id)plot.identifier
                                     componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;

    int fndx = [barID intValue];
    int sndx = index % group.itemCount;
    Item * item = (Item *)[self.plotData objectAtIndex:sndx];

    SEL dataItem = NSSelectorFromString(kTargets[controller.barDataIndex]);
    DataItem * data = [item performSelector:dataItem];
    runs = [[data fldD] doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"BarSelected %@ %@ record:%lu. base:%.2f value:%.2f",
          plot.identifier, data.name, index, floor, value);

    CPTGraph * graph = [self defaultGraph];

    CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation * annotation = self.symbolTextAnnotation;
    if ( annotation )
    {
        [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:annotation];
        self.symbolTextAnnotation = nil;
    }

    // Setup a style for the annotation
    CPTMutableTextStyle * hitAnnotationTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.color    = [CPTColor colorAtIndex:fldMapping[fndx]];
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontSize = 16.0;
    hitAnnotationTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";

    // Determine point of symbol in plot coordinates
    NSNumber * x = @(index);
    NSNumber * y = @(0.03 + (floor / runs));

    CPTNumberArray * anchorPoint = (kUseHorizontalBars ? @[y, x] : @[x, y]);

    // Add annotation
    // First make a string for the y value
    NSString * yString = [[NSNumberFormatter withFormat:@"#,###"] stringFromNumber:@(value)];

    // Now add the annotation to the plot area
    CPTPlotSpace * space = plot.plotSpace;
    if ( space )
    {
        CPTTextLayer * textLayer    = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:yString style:hitAnnotationTextStyle];

        annotation                  = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:space anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
        annotation.contentLayer     = [textLayer autorelease];
        annotation.displacement     = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
        self.symbolTextAnnotation   = annotation;

        [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:[annotation autorelease]];
    }
}

#pragma mark Plot DataSource

- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot
{
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;

    return group.itemCount;
}

- (nullable id)numberForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSString * barID = (NSString *)[[(id)plot.identifier componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;

    int fndx = [barID intValue];
    int sndx = index % group.itemCount;
    Item * item = (Item *)[self.plotData objectAtIndex:sndx];

    SEL dataItem = NSSelectorFromString(kTargets[controller.barDataIndex]);
    NSString * getName = kGetters[fndx];
    SEL getter = NSSelectorFromString(getName);
    SEL fldD = @selector(fldD);
    CGFloat runs, base=0, value=0;
    DataItem * data;
    id num=nil;

    //  First get which data data item we're after
    data = [item performSelector:dataItem];
    runs = [[data performSelector:fldD] floatValue];

    //  Now fetch its getter
    switch ( fieldEnum )
    {
        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            num = item.numb;
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            //  Build base for this tip
            for (int seg=0; seg < fndx; seg++)
            {
                value += [[data performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(kGetters[seg])] floatValue];
            }

            //  Add this 'tip' value unless it's the total
            if (fndx == 3)
                num = @(1.0f);
            else
            {
                value += [[data performSelector:getter] floatValue];
                num = @(value/runs);
            }
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase:
            //  Calc base by sum prior fields
            for (int seg=0; seg < fndx; seg++)
            {
                base += [[data performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(kGetters[seg])] floatValue];
            }
            num = @(base/runs);
    }

    return num;
}

- (nullable id)valueForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSString * barID = (NSString *)[[(id)plot.identifier componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;

    int fndx = [barID intValue];
    int sndx = index % group.itemCount;
    Item * item = (Item *)[self.plotData objectAtIndex:sndx];

    SEL dataItem = NSSelectorFromString(kTargets[controller.barDataIndex]);
    NSString * getName = kGetters[fndx];
    SEL getter = NSSelectorFromString(getName);
    SEL fldD = @selector(fldD);
    CGFloat runs, value=0;
    DataItem * data;
    id num=nil;

    //  First get which data block we're after
    data = [item performSelector:dataItem];
    runs = [[data performSelector:fldD] floatValue];

    //  Now fetch its getter
    switch ( fieldEnum )
    {
        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            num = item.numb.squish;
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            value = [[data performSelector:getter] floatValue];
            num = @(value);
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase:
            //  Calc base by sum prior fields
            for (int seg=0; seg < fndx; seg++)
            {
                value += [[data performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(kGetters[seg])] floatValue];
            }
            num = @(value);
    }

    return num;
}

- (nullable NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(nonnull CPTBarPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSString * barID = (NSString *)[[(id)plot.identifier componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];
    int fndx = [barID intValue];

    return kGetters[fndx];
}

#pragma mark Plot Legend Delegate

- (void)legend:(CPTLegend *)legend legendEntryForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot wasSelectedAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"legend:%@ index:%lu", plot.identifier, index);
}

#pragma mark Plot Space Delegate

#pragma mark Plot Space Delegate

- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space
      willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange
              forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    CGFloat newLocation = newRange.location.floatValue;
//  CGFloat newLength = newRange.length.floatValue;

    //  Range change to +2 point on data boundary
    if (CPTCoordinateX == coordinate)
    {
        if (newLocation < -0.5)
        {
            return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.5) length:newRange.length];
        }
        else
        if (newLocation > (0.3))
        {
            return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(0.3) length:newRange.length];
        }
    }

    if (CPTCoordinateY == coordinate)
    {
        if (newLocation < (-0.1))
        {
            return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-0.1) length:newRange.length];
        }
        else
        if (newLocation > (0.1))
        {
            return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(0.1) length:newRange.length];
        }
    }
//  CGRect chartBounds = self.defaultGraph.bounds;
//  NSLog(@"old:%@", NSStringFromRect(chartBounds));
//  NSLog(@"new:%@ %@", (coordinate == CPTCoordinateX ? @"X" : @"Y"),[newRange description]);
    return newRange;
}
@end

@implementation InfoBarView
@synthesize barChart;
@synthesize x_title;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //  Get our orig scaling
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.barChart = [[[BarChart alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)clip
{
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    NSImage * webImage = controller.group.track.webImage;
    GroupItem * group = controller.group;
    NSRect rect = [self frame];

    //  Save state so we can restore later
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    //  Draw track image as our view's background
    if (webImage)
    {
        [webImage drawInRect:rect fromRect:[webImage alignmentRect]
                   operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:0.25];
    }

    if (group && !barChart.graphs.count)
    {
        [barChart renderInView:self withTheme:nil animated:YES];
    }

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

@end
```

If there were visible clues - drawn bounding rects, I think a lot of us could benefit from them (I miss those from IB circa v3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `x.labelFormatter = nil;` eliminates the automatic axis labels. If you supply a label formatter and label text style, the axis will create ticks and labels automatically based on the labeling policy.

Comment: Hmm; that line is not sample original;idk where it from but removing throws:
`NSParameterAssert(idx < categories.count); in CPTPlotSpace` ?

Comment: That line came from a different bar example but removing it can be remedied by adding categories:
`[barPlotSpace addCategory:@"Percentage" forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateX];
[barPlotSpace addCategory:@"Entries" forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateY];` but for some reason my plots are now off by 1 (higher) ? ie., bar at 1 now at 2, etc ?
`

Comment: Please show the datasource methods, too. There's something wrong with the way you're using categorical data.

Comment: Full module posted.

Comment: The `barPlotSpace.xRange` is too long—the axis is trying to create labels for locations past the last category.

Comment: Hmm, not following; the range is the number of items I have?  I'm not using horizontal bars. I altered listing to reflect adding a category for each Y values - that is 4 categories per data item, and 1 category added per X category one per item. This was in response to examining the args to the assert which seems to be what it was after, The segv is gone but still no labels?

Comment: Only the x-axis is set up to use categories. It's hard to follow what the data looks like. How many category labels should there be?

Comment: By adding the various categories I got rid of the error and saw tips of the x-axis label; trial and error in altering  the bar plot space and x-axis ranges I'm able to get closer to what I need: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8QzZhjxD4brT2lGRldiSFBMQk0)  I still need to have some things (see arrows) removed and desire the x-axis text style to match the style used at label top. Ideally would like a 2 line x-axis label but all the plots disappear when I tried that (\n) inserted in text.

Comment: I still not sure just what a category is but each bar is 4 plots, sourced from a single item object; It appeared to want n-categories to match the number of items. For good measure I added a Y category for each of the values.

Comment: A categorical axis (e.g., `setScaleType:CPTScaleTypeCategory`) is used to plot data that is grouped into discrete categories instead of numeric values. Internally, Core Plot converts the category labels into a sequence of integer index values between zero (0) and `n-1` (n is the number of categories). It's basically a shortcut so you don't have to keep track of the mapping between categories and index values in your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121007/discussion-between-slashlos-and-eric-skroch).